# Carbon checking hours

Tags: laravel, time, php-carbon

I have function

```
public static function isRestaurantOpen($RestaurantID)
{
    $hours = settings_hours::all();
    $restaurant = [];
    foreach ($hours as $hour) {
        if ($hour->place_id == $RestaurantID) {
            $restaurant = $hour;
        }
    }


    if(!$restaurant) return "Time not set";
    
    $opening_hours = $restaurant->opening_hours;


    $date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d', time())); //get date
    $day = strtolower(date_format($date, 'l')); //get day of date

    
    $now = Carbon::now()->addHours(2); //im added this because i have wrong time on the server
    $start = Carbon::createFromTimeString($opening_hours[$day]['from']); //from hour
    $end = Carbon::createFromTimeString($opening_hours[$day]['to']); //to hour

    if ($now->between($start, $end)) {
        return "Open"; 
    } else {
        return "Close";
    }
}
```

But this function does not work correctly if it compares time in 24 hour format.
Anyone can help me with this? Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't want to re-code your own stuff, use the dedicated official Carbon mixin: https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i find function in another question and this function works well

```
public static function isNowBetweenTimes($timezone, $startDateTime, $endDateTime) {
    $curTimeLocal = Carbon::now($timezone);
    $startTime = $curTimeLocal->copy();
    $startTime->hour = $startDateTime->hour;
    $startTime->minute = $startDateTime->minute;
    $endTime = $curTimeLocal->copy();
    $endTime->hour = $endDateTime->hour;
    $endTime->minute = $endDateTime->minute;
    if ($endTime->lessThan($startTime))
        $endTime->addDay();

    return ($curTimeLocal->isBetween($startTime, $endTime));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to add more than an hour, you should use addHours 'with s' not addHour ...

```
    $now = Carbon::now()->addHours(2);
    $start = Carbon::parse($opening_hours[$day]['from']);
    $end = Carbon::parse($opening_hours[$day]['to']);
```

now this code should work:

```
 if ($now->between($start, $end)) {
        return "Open"; 
    } else {
        return "Close";
    }
```

Comment: Still not work :(
For example, if I have hours from 08:00 AM to 01:00 PM it shows that it is closed

Comment: i have test it, it works just fine, perhaps you should remove ->addHours(2) from 
$now = Carbon::now()->addHours(2);

Comment: i remove addhours, still not working, test this based on this

now time: 2020-06-25 20:41:42.360117 UTC (+00:00)
from hours: 2020-06-25 11:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
to hours: 2020-06-25 01:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)

and result is closed

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you have opening hours defined for each day, which is exactly the purpose of business-time mixin mentioned in the Carbon documentation:

https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time

This will very likely do the job for you.